# Почему нужно указывать количество столбцов массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Есть массив:

```
int a[5][5];
```

И есть функция:

```
int foo(int d[][5])
{
    return 1;
}
```

Почему нельзя передать в функцию двумерный массив как указатель на указатель?
И почему нужно обязательно указывать количество столбцов?т.е **int d[ ][ ]** нельзя так передать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что указатель на указатель - это совсем другая структура (другое размещение элементов в памяти). Это массив указателей, где каждый указывает на еще один одномерный массив где-то в другом месте памяти.

Двумерный же массив - это единый блок памяти, и компилятор должен знать, где заканчивается одна строка и начинается вторая. И если это ему не указать, как вы предлагаете - то как найти нужное место в этом блоке?...

Comment: то есть адрес двумерного массива никак нельзя получить?точнее присвоить какому нибудь указателю

Comment: и если,например есть двойной указатель 'arr' типа int,почему нельзя  обращаться к элементам массива n[6][5] так *(*(arr+3)+3).Ведь arr+3 это есть arr+sizeof(type)*3 и в памяти получается все так же упорядочено как и с двумерным массивом

Comment: 1. Адрес получить можно, но это не адрес массива указателей, а адрес одной "макаронины" в памяти, которая просто делится на строки. 2. Можно. Только чему у вас равен size(type), если вы передаете `int arr[][]`? Без указания размера строки?

Comment: Harry,а как получить тогда адрес начала этой "макаронины"?Я пишу  int a[5][5]; int  *b= a; И у меня выдает ошибку преобразования.Но ведь 'a' имеет тип указателя,не так ли,и из за чего тогда ошибка?

Comment: @Whitehorse, `int *b = &a[0];`

Comment: ヒミコ ,а почему нельзя как я написал? 'a'  имеет же тип указателя

Comment: `a` имеет тип `int[5][5]`. Попробуйте `int * b = &a[0][0];`

Answer (score 2):

Массив `int a[5][5];` может неявно преобразовываться к указателю на первый элемент, т.е. к указателю на массив из 5 `int`, что и происходит при передаче его в функцию. Однако нет никакого контекста, при котором он мог бы преобразоваться к указателю на указатель. Для такого преобразования требуется чтобы элементы массива были указателями, т.е. чтобы изначально был `int * a[5];`.

Аргумент вида `int d[][]` вызовет ошибку, так как в С++ нельзя объявлять массивы из незавершенных (incomplete) типов, к которым относится любой массив неизвестной длины.

Скорее всего тут, как в 80% случаев, использование массива массивов не нужно. И вместо `int a[5][5];` лучше использовать `::std::array<int, 5 * 5> a;` или `vector`, а вместо указателя `int d[][5]` передавать `::std::span<int, 5 * 5>` или по ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, массив - это не указатель, массив - это массив. Хотя он может в некоторых ситуациях неявно преобразовываться к указателю на свой первый элемент.

Во-вторых, `n`-мерный массив, `n > 1`, на самом деле является одномерным массивом, элементами которого являются `n-1`-мерные массивы.

```
int arr[2][5]={{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}};//Массив из двух элементов типа (массив из пяти элементов типа int)

int (*p1)[2][5]; //Указатель на массив из двух элементов типа (массив из пяти элементов типа int)
int (*p2)[5]; //Указатель на массив из пяти элементов типа int
int* p3; //Указатель на int

p1 = &arr; //p1 указывает на массив arr;
p2 = &arr[0]; //p2 указывает на первый элемент массива arr, т.е. на массив из пяти элементов типа int
p3 = &arr[0][0]; //p3 указывает на первый элемент первого подмассива массива arr

cout << sizeof(arr) << " " << sizeof(*p1) << endl; //2 * 5 * sizeof(int)
cout << sizeof(arr[0]) << " " << sizeof(*p2) << endl; //5 * sizeof(int)
cout << sizeof(arr[0][0]) << " " << sizeof(*p3) << endl; //sizeof(int)

cout << sizeof(p1) << " " << sizeof(p2) << " " << sizeof(p3) << endl; //Вывод зависит от реализации. Как вариант, "8 8 8" или "4 4 4".

//Массив может быть неявно преобразован к указателю на свой первый элемент:
arr + 1; //Указатель на второй подмассив массива arr
*(arr + 1) + 4; //Указатель на 5 элемент второго подмассива массива arr
cout << *(*(arr + 1) + 4) << endl; //9
```

В-третьих, массив не может быть параметром функции. Всё что похоже на массив в параметре функции на самом деле интерпретируется как указатель на элемент массива.

```
void f(int* arr0, int arr1[], int arr2[5], int arr3[2][5], int (* arr4)[2][5])
{
    //arr0, arr1 и arr2 имеют одинаковый тип - указатель на int
    //arr3 - указатель на массив из пяти элементов типа int.
    //arr4 - указатель на массив из двух элементов типа (массив из пяти элементов типа int)
    cout << 
        is_same<decltype(arr0), int *>::value <<  //1
        is_same<decltype(arr1), int *>::value <<  //1
        is_same<decltype(arr2), int *>::value <<  //1
        is_same<decltype(arr3), int (*)[5]>::value <<  //1
        is_same<decltype(arr4), int (*)[2][5]>::value << endl;  //1
}
```

Comment: А почему в строке где мы выводим размеры в байтах указателей,у нас одинаковое количество байт выводит?Ведь это по сути указатели на объект и должен выводиться размер тех объектов на которые указывают указатели (так как указатель без унарных знаков возвращает адрес на который указывает)

Comment: Нет, `sizeof` находит размер непосредственно того объекта, к которому он применяется, а указатель - это тоже объект. Он занимает некоторое количество байт, имеет некоторый адрес, а также можно объявлять указатели, которые указывают на другие указатели. Если бы `sizeof` разыменовывал указатель и выводил размер объекта, на который он указывает, то как бы можно было узнать размер указателя? :)

Comment: и где вы передаете указатель arr3 в функцию,может все таки указатель на массив из ДЕСЯТИ элементов а не ПЯТИ?

Comment: wololo,ну просто меня смутило когда мы пишем sizeof(p1) и sizeof(&p1) выводит одно и то же

Comment: Посмотрите предыдущий пример кода. Там был массив `int arr[2][5]`. Это массив из ДВУХ элементов. И эти элементы сами являются массивами. Каждый из ПЯТИ элементов. Итого в массив `arr` "запаковано"  2 * 5 = 10 элементов типа `int`. Однако, когда мы указываем массив в качестве параметра функции, то он интерпретируется не как массив, а как указатель на свой первый элемент. Первый элемент `arr3` - это массив из ПЯТИ элементов. То есть `arr3` - это указатель на массив из пяти элементов.

Comment: `sizeof(p1)` вычисляет размер указателя `p1`. `&p1` вычисляет адрес указателя `p1`. `sizeof(&p1)` вычисляет размер указателя, который может указывать на указатель `p1`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!!